# Extracting information from a JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I would like to get the average temperature. I'm not any good with recognising formats but I'm pretty sure result is parsed json. To see how I'm using results and what I've already tired to do here is the code I'm using along with the openWeatherMapAPI iOS wrapper link:

https://github.com/adba/OpenWeatherMapAPI

I run this method:

```
[weatherAPI dailyForecastWeatherByCityName:destination 
                                 withCount:time 
                               andCallback:^(NSError *error, NSDictionary *result) {
```

result looks like this:

```
 clouds = 32;
    deg = 123;
    dt = "2013-12-02 11:00:00 +0000";
    humidity = 86;
    pressure = "1039.92";
    speed = "1.41";
    temp =     {
        day = "8.429986572265648";
        eve = "6.420007324218773";
        max = "8.429986572265648";
        min = "1.339990234375023";
        morn = "2.189996337890648";
        night = "1.339990234375023";
    };
    weather =     (
                {
            description = "nuages \U00e9parses";
            icon = 03d;
            id = 802;
            main = Clouds;
        }
    );
}
```

.h:

```
OWMWeatherAPI *weatherAPI;

NSArray *forecast;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
```

.m:

```
    [weatherAPI dailyForecastWeatherByCityName:destination withCount:time andCallback:^(NSError *error, NSDictionary *result) {
        if (error) {

            [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            activityIndicator.hidden = YES;

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please verify you have an internet connection and that the city name is spelled correclty with no spaces afterwars or before it." delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alert show];
        }

        // The data is ready

        forecast = result[@"list"];

        [self.forecastTableView reloadData];
    }];
}

#pragma mark - forecast tableview datasource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return forecast.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    NSDictionary *forecastData = [forecast objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f℃ - %@", [forecastData[@"main"][@"temp"] floatValue], forecastData[@"weather"][0][@"main"]
                           ];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:forecastData[@"dt"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: what is your problem here?

Comment: Your first listing is neither JSON nor is it an NSDictionary dump.  Your second listing is apparently an NSDictionary that may be parsed JSON, but it does not very closely match the first listing -- they are most likely not using the same scheme.  You first need to identify what format you're actually going to work with, then figure out the details of it.  There's no magic formula -- it's just work.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with JSon , parsing etc... maybe my code can help? I basicaly want to get the average temperature.

Comment: If you want to get the average temperature you must understand how to query the server, get the result back, parse it, and then extract the desired information from the parsed result.  A big part of that is understanding the format of the data sent by the server.  You haven't really given us a clue as to what that is.

Comment: I have re-written the question. Sorry for not being clear hopefully you can understand better now.

Comment: Please remove from hold I have found my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive error and trial I found how to get any value for any key in that file.
The error lied in this line:

```
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f℃ - %@", [forecastData[@"main"][@"temp"] floatValue], forecastData[@"weather"][0][@"main"]
```

To get the day value in temp you need to do this:

```
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f℃ - %@", [forecastData[@"day"][@"temp"] floatValue], forecastData[@"weather"][0][@"main"]
```

Or let's say the humidity:

```
  .....[@"humidity"].....
```